# Does chain_id exist in any smart contracts?

Tags: json-rpc, sidechain

Is `chainId` something any smart contracts have knowledge of, or does it only exist externally to any given chain?

I see the [eth_chainId](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_chainId) function of the JSON-RPC. But are there any ABI queries against contracts which would deal with chain_id as a field or return type at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, smart contracts can access [**`block.chainid`**](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) if it is required by the business logic.